# goodness-of-fit and bootstrap

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

Assume one has two data samples: $X = \{ x_{1}, \dots, x_{n} \}$ and $Y = \{y_{1}, \dots, y_{m}\}$. Next, we aim to check if the data $Y$ was generated by the same data generating process (DGP) as $X$ did. Assume that $m \ll n$, i.e. the second data sample is smaller than the first one.

Would it increase a power of goodness-of-fit test if we "increase" a second data set with some proper bootstraping?

Comment: You seem to have embarked on a series of questions of the form "if I tried X, would it be any good?" where it appears you are considering a single statistical problem.  Instead you will likely find it much more productive to ask a single question of the form "here is the kind of data I have, here is the objective of my analysis, what would be a good approach?"

Comment: Dear @whuber, yes, I agree that it is a rather blurry question. In this subject now I am mostly interested in a theoretical aspects of sampling techniques and this is why the statement was "too general".

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrapping is a procedure that uses random sampling with replacement. You maybe talking about oversampling technique to increase the size of your dataset. You can use oversampling techniques like nearest neighbours or variants of it to simulate the dataset. It will generally increase the goodness of fit test since you will have more data points to fit your model but oversampling doesn't always increase model performance especially when you have noisy data.